# Sum of max grouped by column

Tags: powerbi, sum, max, dax

What I want to achieve is to create table where I can display a list of items with max values, but grouped with another dimension.

Here is the example:
[[image: expected result]

Have tried this, but the result is wrong

```
sum_of_max = SUMX(VALUES(T1[dimension1]),CALCULATE(MAX(T1[Value])))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post data as text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use this measure instead:

```
sum_of_max = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(T1[value]),
    T1[value] = MAX(T1[value])
)
```